# If $A$ depends on $B,C$ and $B,C$ are independent, if $A$ is now observed, is $B,C$ still independent?

Tags: random-variables, independence

$A,B,C$ are random variables. The question states $A$ depends on $B,C$, and that $B,C$ are independent. Now if $A$ is now observed, are $B,C$ still independent?

I don't know if this is a trick question, if I'm misunderstanding something, or if it's poorly worded. It states that $B,C$ are independent and did not make references to $A$ when making the independency claim, so wouldn't $B,C$ still be independent?

But what if we had a relation like $A = B + C$. If $A$ is now known, then couldn't $B$ be written in terms of $C$ and vice versa, which seems to imply dependency?

Comment: What is $Z$ that you now observed?

Comment: @user10354138 I'm sorry. I had a typo where $Z$ should have bene $A$. I just corrected it.

Comment: The wording is not very good.  Of course, if a mathematical statement is true then it is always true, and literally, $B,C$ are still independent no matter what other information is given.  What the question intends to ask is whether $B,C$ are **conditionally independent given $A$**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what if we had a relation like $A=B+C$. If $A$ is now known, then couldn't $B$ be written in terms of $C$ and vice versa, which seems to imply dependency?

Indeed.  As your counterexample has demonstrated, the independence of $B$ and $C$ does *not entail* that they will be *conditionally* independent when given $A$.

---

Toss two fair coins, let $B$ be the count for heads showing on the left coin (so $0$ or $1$), $C$ the count for heads showing on the right, and $A$ the count for heads showing on both coins.

Random variables $B$ and $C$ are independent — since knowing the value for $B$ imparts no information about the value for $C$ — but not conditionally independent when given that, for example, $A=1$ — since knowing the value for $B$, when given the value for $A$, now *determines* the value for $C$ (since $C=A-B$).

Comment: I do understand this logic; however, I feel like the premise of $A = B+C$ implies that B and C are dependent? Because clearly we can rearrange the equation to be $B = A - C$, where it is more clear that $B$ is a function of $C$? So if we have such a relation like A = B+C, isn't there an underlying dependency going on?

Comment: @dd22205 In the example, the states of $B$ and $C$ are independent *when you do not know the value of $A$*. It is knowledge about the condition of $A$ which makes them dependent (hence it is called *conditional* dependency.)

Comment: I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this although I do understand conditional dependency. I'm looking at it from a purely algebraic perspective and essentially disregarding probability theory in that if we rearrange $A=B+C$, this allows us to see that $B = A-C$ and $C = A-B$, where if you take the LHS as the output, then it seems to say that the output is dependent on B/C. That is, $B = A-C$ holds regardless of whether A is observed or unobserved right?

Comment: @dd22205 Yes, but when you do *not know anything* about the value for $A$, then what would information on the value of $B$ actually change about your expectation for the values of $C$?

Comment: If we have the information that $B$ is, say, positive, wouldn't we expect $C$ to be smaller than if $B$ is, say, negative? Although this seems to assume that we're dealing with the same realization of $A$ in both cases, which seems like it is not a valid assumption. But can we take a frequentist perspective and say in the long run, even if we don't know $A$, we can expect that $C$ to be smaller if $B > 0$ compared to $B < 0$?

Comment: No.   For instance, in the given example, unless we know the count of heads shown on both coins ($A$), then *how* does knowing what the left coin shows ($B$) affect the probability that the right coin shows heads ($C=1$)?